# react js state variable updates automatically without setstate method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react js project. I have a state variable and I initialize that state variable (`x_state`) with another normal variable (`x`) during the `componentDidMount()` method. 
But whenever my normal variable (`x`) gets updated it is automatically updating the state variable (`x_state`).

```
export class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x_state: null
    }
    this.x = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      x_state: this.x
    })
  }
}
```

The local variable this.x is updating on specific conditions inside the code. whenever the local variable this.x is updating it is automatically updating the state variable x_state. 
How to prevent the automatic update or automatic setstate method invoking

Comment: `this.x` is an object and you're setting it to `x_state` in `setState`. They are both pointing to the same object in memory. Since, `x` is an empty object literal, why not set  `this.setState({
      x_state: {}
    })`? Why even use `this.x` in componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maheer Ali & @adiga are correct. Since the state variable `x_state` and the local variable `this.x` point to the same object in memory, they both update in conjunction.

You may also use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the properties of the local object to the state variable.

```
this.setState({
   x_state: { ...this.x }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `x` is an object and you are setting the reference by this code

```
this.setState({
   x_state: this.x
})
```

You should make a copy of it using `Object.assign()`

```
this.setState({
      x_state: Ojbect.assign({},this.x)
})
```

Or if `this.x` is a nested object initially you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
this.setState({
     x_state: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.x))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**ECMAScript 6** defines seven data types:
**Six data types that are primitives**: Boolean, Null, Undefined, Number, String, Symbol and **Object**.

> Primitive Data Types are passed By Value and Objects are passed By
>   Reference.

So when you think you're "assigning" the value of an `obj1 = obj2` you're actually creating a reference in (`obj1`) 'pointing' towards (`obj2`), so any changes in (`obj2`) will automatically be made in (`obj1`).
You could use any of the answers above or use a spread operator, any method that returns a **shallow copy** of the object you want to copy.
Here is an intersting [post on the topic](https://hackernoon.com/grasp-by-value-and-by-reference-in-javascript-7ed75efa1293).